# Google maps api - NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I get errors while trying to use google maps api on my instance. The error message is:

```
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200
```

This is my helmet configuration:

```
  app.use(
    helmet({
      crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
          scriptSrc: [
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            'https://maps.googleapis.com',
          ],
          connectSrc: ["'self'", 'https://maps.googleapis.com'],
          'img-src': ["'self'", 'https: data:'],
        },
      },
    }),
  );
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this kind of problem? Thanks in advance for any advices.